# A/C blower does not work after a power surge

Tags: hvac

My outside unit works but my inside unit does nit turn on, its a bryant a/c system. On the unit it says the circuit board is built into the blower motor. The transformer buzzes. Can I replace the circuit board without replacing the blower motor?

Comment: Sure, if you can get "just that part" (depends how "built-in" it is - sometimes you cannot even get individual parts of an assembly, at least from the manufacturer) but without first isolating where the actual problem is, replacing any particular part may not fix the problem. Throwing parts at a problem that's not fully diagnosed can be quite expensive.

Comment: If the blower motor is line voltage AC, you can test it by disconnecting it from the inner workings and connecting it directly to an AC line cord and plugging it in.   Of course you run the risk of shocking yourself and having fingers mangled by the fan.   But it's a simple test.  Just be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Which facts are known about that power surge? Lightning stroke, switching activities in the provider's net? If there is a proof of liability, it could be an insurance case.

A voltage surge could have destroyed the surge protectors and/or the related fuses. Power has to be disconnected, line capacitors have to be discharged before any work. The exchange of those most probable soldered parts should be no big issue if some basic electr(on)ic knowledge is available.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the "start"capacitor , if that motor has one.

Answer (score 0):

I Have not dealt with this exact problem,it could be the blower motor is faulty,a buzzing sound maybe locked bearings or winding fault,can not be more precise with inormation I have,Steve uk engineer best wishes.It occured to me the buzzing noise maybe condensate pump running.NOises can be hard to pinpoint,check this out first.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a surge is more likely to have damaged the control electronics rather than the motor ...